# How do I modify the default grey background for the Discussion App. See Attached picture

Tags: sharepoint-online, app, format, background, discussion

[image]

I need to either stretch the grey background or remove it.  I have not figure out how to modify this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use developer tool(F12) to find the element, then you could add CSS/js to change the style of the element you find.

[image]
You can see the attributes of the element. Then you can change the style of the element according to these attributes, but you need to ensure that these attributes can be uniquely positioned to the corresponding element.

Test CSS for your reference:

```
    <style>
    .ms-comm-rootBestBackground{
     background-color:red
    }
    </style>
```